# Are X.509 certificates tied to a particular operation

Tags: encryption, certificates, x.509

I am looking to create a X.509 certificate to encrypt a payload (plaintext) (using Hybrid encryption) and send it across to a server. Can I create a SSL/TLS X.509 certificate and use that to do the encryption? Or is there a X.509 that I need to create separate for this?

Comment: Note that for encryption only you don't need a certificate - only a key is needed. A certificate is usually part of some PKI and "encryption" is usually used in the context of some larger standard like S/MIME, so a certificate needs to adhere to what PKI and S/MIME requires.